# How to setup cmake to link parallel boost-graph?

Tags: c++, boost-graph, boost-mpi, boost-graph-parallel

I am trying to set up CMake such that boost-graph is properly linked. But I am running into an error when doing

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS graph mpi) # finding mpi is a problem
```

```
-- Found boost_mpi 1.77.0 at ~/miniconda3/envs/xyz/lib/cmake/boost_mpi-1.77.0
--   Library has no variants and is considered not found
CMake Error at /home/tom/miniconda3/envs/pokeai/lib/cmake/Boost-1.77.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    ~/miniconda3/envs/xyz/lib/cmake/boost_mpi-1.77.0/boost_mpi-config.cmake

  but it set boost_mpi_FOUND to FALSE so package "boost_mpi" is considered to
  be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  No suitable build variant has been found.
```

I have tried to find a doc from Boost-graph for this but it seems like the cmake part is not there for the setup. A line from `boost_mpi-config.cmake` looks suspicious to me and it is related to the error.

To produce the problem locally, you might find the files below useful.

CMakeLists.txt used:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

set(Boost_VERBOSE ON)
message(CHECK_START "Looking for MPI")
find_package(MPI REQUIRED COMPONENTS CXX C)

#find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS graph)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS graph mpi) # finding mpi is a problem
add_executable(parallel_boost_graph parallel_boost_graph.cpp)

target_link_libraries(parallel_boost_graph
        PUBLIC
        MPI::MPI_CXX
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        Boost::graph
        #        Boost::mpi
        )
```

A small example code to reproduce the problem:

```
// Enable PBGL interfaces to BGL algorithms
#include <boost/graph/use_mpi.hpp>

// Communication via MPI
#include <boost/graph/distributed/mpi_process_group.hpp>

// Dijkstra's single-source shortest paths algorithm
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>

// Distributed adjacency list
#include <boost/graph/distributed/adjacency_list.hpp>

// METIS Input
#include <boost/graph/metis.hpp>

// Graphviz Output
#include <boost/graph/distributed/graphviz.hpp>

// Standard Library includes
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#ifdef BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS
void boost::throw_exception(std::exception const& ex) {
  std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
  abort();
}
#endif

using namespace boost;
using boost::graph::distributed::mpi_process_group;

/* An undirected, weighted graph with distance values stored on the
vertices. */
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, distributedS<mpi_process_group, vecS>, undirectedS,
                       /*Vertex properties=*/property<vertex_distance_t, float>,
                       /*Edge properties=*/property<edge_weight_t, float> >
    Graph;

using namespace boost;
using boost::graph::distributed::mpi_process_group;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  boost::mpi::environment env(argc, argv);

  typedef adjacency_list<listS, distributedS<mpi_process_group, vecS>,
                         directedS,
                         no_property,                  // Vertex properties
                         property<edge_weight_t, int>  // Edge properties
                         >
      graph_t;
  typedef graph_traits<graph_t>::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
  typedef graph_traits<graph_t>::edge_descriptor edge_descriptor;

  typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;
  const int num_nodes = 5;
  enum nodes { A, B, C, D, E };
  char name[] = "ABCDE";
  Edge edge_array[] = {Edge(A, C), Edge(B, B), Edge(B, D),
                       Edge(B, E), Edge(C, B), Edge(C, D),
                       Edge(D, E), Edge(E, A), Edge(E, B)};
  int weights[] = {1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1};
  int num_arcs = sizeof(edge_array) / sizeof(Edge);

  graph_t g(edge_array, edge_array + num_arcs, weights, num_nodes);
  // Keeps track of the predecessor of each vertex
  std::vector<vertex_descriptor> p(num_vertices(g));
  // Keeps track of the distance to each vertex
  std::vector<int> d(num_vertices(g));

  vertex_descriptor s = vertex(A, g);
  dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, s,
                          predecessor_map(make_iterator_property_map(
                                              p.begin(), get(vertex_index, g)))
                              .distance_map(make_iterator_property_map(
                                  d.begin(), get(vertex_index, g))));

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

For your convenience, you can also check out this repo to reproduce the problem:
https://bitbucket.org/cpchung/debugging-only

Comment: Do you actually need PBGL? Your question title only mentions Boost Graph (BGL) which is 99% header-only. You only need to link for reading certain file formats

Comment: The example c++ code shown above needs the parallel part. E.g. the #include <boost/graph/distributed/adjacency_list.hpp>

Answer (score 1):

The parallel Boost.Graph library needs Boost.MPI. The CMake find process (or better: the Boost.MPI CMake config files) tell you

> No suitable build variant has been found.

This happens when there are no `libboost_mpi-variant-*.cmake` files next to  `boost_mpi-config.cmake` which is the case when there was an error in packaging (e.g. however copied the files to the final destination missed those) or the Boost.MPI library simply was not build. I suspect the latter.

So what you need to do is either get a Boost installation containing Boost.MPI via whatever package manager you use which could be as simple as installing a single additional package in case the Boost libraries were split into individual packages. Or you can build & install Boost from source yourself making sure the `b2` command can find the MPI headers and hence Boost.MPI is build.

Note: Using the CMake variables `Boost_DEBUG` and `Boost_VERBOSE` (set them via `cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON`) can help in finding why a library was not found or rejected.

Comment: Much appreciated. These are the finicky edge cases I don't use often. Do you have a recommendation between OpenMPI/MPICH when building from source?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by that.

I tried not to use conda and install boost and its components:
`
sudo apt install libboost-mpi-dev
sudo apt install libboost-graph-dev
sudo apt install libboost-graph-parallel-dev
`
Still seeing the similar error.

Comment: Check that the Boost.MPI is actually installed (in conda path or system path), i.e. that there is a `libboost_mpi.so` (or similar) and at least 1 `libboost_mpi-variant*.cmake` file (when Boost is installed with a `boost_mpi-config.cmake`)

Comment: checked. Still cannot build it